# Expand a congested x axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a ggplot that has 86 items on each axis. I am trying to adjust the text labels/ticks so that it can be properly read. At the moment I can only produce a plot that does not provide enough space for the text on the x axis. Please see photo.

[image: photo]

Here are selected values from the dataframe that is being plotted:

```
     Var1 Var2     value   group
1       1    1 1.0000000 Group 1
2       2    1 0.7086322 Group 1
1654   20   20 1.0000000 Group 2
1657   23   20 0.7037037 Group 2
2524   30   30 1.0000000 Group 3
2526   32   30 0.8466508 Group 3
4177   49   49 1.0000000 Group 4
4186   58   49 0.7201761 Group 4
5830   68   68 1.0000000 Group 5
5837   75   68 0.8125000 Group 5
6700   78   78 1.0000000 Group 6
6701   79   78 0.8402689 Group 6
```

This is what I have so far:

```
assign.colour<-c("#8DA0CB","#66C2A5","#A6D854","#E5C494","#E78AC3","#FC8D62")
p<-ggplot(data=df,aes(Var1,Var2)) + geom_tile(data=df,aes(fill=group),color="grey")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = assign.colour)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,margin = margin(1, unit = "cm")))+
  scale_x_discrete(position="top")
p
```

I also tried `expand=c(0,0)` but it didn't do anything. I tried `hjust=-0.1` and it moved the labels above the border of plot but the spacing was still too tight for reading. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this

```
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,margin = margin(1, unit = "cm"),vjust =1))
```

or you can adjust size in `element_text`

```
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,size = rel(0.5), margin = margin(1, unit = "cm"),vjust =1))
```

lastly, save your plot as image with larger size.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried working on the plotting device dimensions?

If it is pdf,

```
pdf( "output.pdf", width = xx, height = yy )
```

Please refer the following for tick spaces as well:

[Change distance between x-axis ticks in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400486/change-distance-between-x-axis-ticks-in-ggplot2)

Comment: I tried the angle =90 and it is readable, but still difficult because one has to tilt their head, and the labels are center aligned so longer text protrude while shorter ones don't, giving a wavy appearance. The size = rel(0.5) made it too small. I tried outputting the dimensions as 1024x768 and the labels are still crunched.

Comment: input data is an abundance matrix?plz  share the structure of input data and the code used to create data frame (just to replicate your problem first). will try on my end and revert back