# How do I bring grouped bars closer together in a grouped bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a grouped bar chart with ggplot2. I have this code...

```
ggplot(data = dummy,
       aes(
         fill = Geography2,
         x = Group,
         y = PunishmentRate
       )
) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "dodge",
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.5,
    binwidth = 0
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(data = subset(dummy, Group == "White"),
            aes(
              label = Geography2,
              y = 0
            ),
            position = position_dodge(0.5),
            hjust = 0
  )
```

That makes this chart...

[image]

I thought adding `binwidth` parameter in `geom_bar()` would bring the groups closer together, but it did not. How do I bring the groups closer together?

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400486/change-distance-between-x-axis-ticks-in-ggplot2

Comment: @aosmith I want to keep the bars narrow

Comment: Try making the "wide" bars but then adjust the final height of the plot you save.  This way you can still make the bars narrow.